# Need to perform image verification in appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

As per project requirement, I need to perform image verification using appium. The scenario like In our application,
A user need to send message but only when the image icon beside its name become green (So image transition happened from Black->Yellow->Green). User button is always click able so i think there is no point to wait until it became click able. so only way left for me is to wait until image colour is being changed. The problem is that all images replaces at same page element , so all three images have same resource-id by watching it from uiautomatorviewer. so please suggest any alternative way to solve this issue?

Thanks,

Priyank Shah

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the element based on its CSS attribute (color for example).